# Download seems to not start

Tags: javascript, puppeteer

I try to download a file with puppeeter by a save button who is valable after clicking on button export (javascript)

example url https://fr.semrush.com/fr/info/cinema+(full+search)

[image]

So with puppeeter the first click action (on red in the picture) work.
The second click action on "sauvegarder" or "save" in english didn't work (in fact, if you use it normaly, the file is downloading).

Here's my full code (for french version o fsemrush)

```
// Import package
const fs = require('fs');
const rl = require('readline');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

// **** function to read list of keywords then extract by download
// **** file must be encodeed in UTF8 BOM mode


// ***** semrush login
// ***** this function generates the way of the cookies cramble for all futur actions on semrush 
const semrushlog = async () => {

  // we create a chrome session - set headless to true if you don't want to see the browser pop-up
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false })

  // we setup a new tab in our browser - here we go mario (wouhouu)
  const page = await browser.newPage()

  try {

      // define the browser size on screen - important if you wana screenshot for example ;)
      //await page.setViewport({ width: 1000, height: 500 })

      // navigate to semrush home
      await page.goto('https://fr.semrush.com/fr/info/cinema+(full+search)')


      //page result button
      const exportBtn = '#PhraseDetailed > div.sem-widget-header > div > div.sem-widget-footer-rb.sem-widget-footer-export-links > div > button'
      const downloadBtn = '#PhraseDetailed > div.sem-widget-header > div > div.sem-widget-footer-rb.sem-widget-footer-export-links > div > div > div.s-dropdown__block.clearfix > button > span'



      // load page search keywords 





        //debug -- check number of page in array
        //console.log(generatedPages[0])

        // get our semrush data
        var generatedPageLength = generatedPages.length

        await page._client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', {behavior: 'allow', downloadPath: 'C:/QCD/puppeteer/'})


            console.log(generatedPages[i])

            await page.goto(generatedPages[i])
            //download the file
            await page.click(exportBtn)

            await page.waitFor(2*1000)

            // **** btn download doesn't fire the file download
            // ****
            await page.click(downloadBtn)


            //page.waitForNavigation('load')
            //wait 5s
            await page.waitFor(15*1000)



  } catch (err) {
        console.log("caught an exception", err);
        await browser.close();
        return
    }

}



// call our semrush function
semrushlog()
```

Thanks for your help in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

```
// Import package
const fs = require('fs');
const rl = require('readline');
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

// **** function to read list of keywords then extract by download
// **** file must be encodeed in UTF8 BOM mode
// ***** semrush login
// ***** this function generates the way of the cookies cramble for all futur actions on semrush 

const semrushlog = async () => {
  // we create a chrome session - set headless to true if you don't want to see the browser pop-up
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false })

  // we setup a new tab in our browser - here we go mario (wouhouu)
  const page = await browser.newPage()

  try {

      // define the browser size on screen - important if you wana screenshot for example ;)
      //await page.setViewport({ width: 1000, height: 500 })

      // navigate to semrush home
      await page.goto('https://fr.semrush.com/fr/info/cinema+(full+search)')


      //page result button
      const exportBtn = '#PhraseDetailed > div.sem-widget-header > div > div.sem-widget-footer-rb.sem-widget-footer-export-links > div > button'
      const downloadBtn = '#PhraseDetailed > div.sem-widget-header > div > div.sem-widget-footer-rb.sem-widget-footer-export-links > div > div > div.s-dropdown__block.clearfix > button > span'

      // load page search keywords 
        //debug -- check number of page in array
        //console.log(generatedPages[0])
        // get our semrush data
        var generatedPageLength = generatedPages.length
        await page._client.send('Page.setDownloadBehavior', {behavior: 'allow', downloadPath: 'C:/QCD/puppeteer/'})
            console.log(generatedPages[i])
            await page.goto(generatedPages[i])
            //download the file
            await page.click(exportBtn)
            await page.waitFor(2*1000)
            // **** btn download doesn't fire the file download
            // ****
            await page.click(downloadBtn)
            //page.waitForNavigation('load')
            //wait 5s
            await page.waitFor(15*1000)
  } catch (err) {
        console.log("caught an exception", err);
        await browser.close();
        return
    }

}


(async () => {
    // call our semrush function
    await semrushlog()
})();
```

Comment: sorry but I didn't see the difference between what I do and what you purpose as a solution start for my problem

Comment: @Yeurl
(async () => {
    await semrushlog();
})();

Comment: @Yeurl 
http://2ality.com/2016/10/async-function-tips.html#immediately-invoked-async-function-expressions

Comment: ok thanks - still no download start with your suggest. May be due to je js activation then the buton "save" (in french sauvegarder) is not in the page at the load (in fact is not visible until the first click). I mind if I should try to activate the dowload action by element function ?